# javascript - potential infinite loop when comparing with arguments.length

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to write a for-loop that goes trough all the inputs of a function, compares the elements of the inputs, and outputs unique elements (in this case they will always be numbers).

Since this is a [freecodecamp exercise](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/sorted-union#?solution=function%20unite%28arr1%2C%20arr2%2C%20arr3%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2Ffor%20all%20arrays%0A%20%20var%20output%20%3D%20arr1%3B%0A%20%20for%28var%20x%20%3D%200%3B%20x%20%3C%20arguments.length%3B%20x%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%28var%20y%20%3D%200%3B%20y%20%3C%20arguments[x].length%3B%20y%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%28var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20output.length%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%28arguments[x][y]%20!%3D%3D%20output[i]%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20output.push%28arguments[x][y]%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20output%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aunite%28[1%2C%203%2C%202]%2C%20[5%2C%202%2C%201%2C%204]%2C%20[2%2C%201]%29%3B%0A), I get some feedback, and get the following error: `Error: potential infinite loop at line 4.`

If I run the loop, without the infinite loop protection I get out of memory. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
function unite(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
  //for all arrays
  var output = arr1;
  for(var x = 0; x < arguments.length; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < arguments[x].length; y++) {
      for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        if(arguments[x][y] !== output[i]) {
          output.push(arguments[x][y]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}

unite([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

Comment: Is it because you are looping through output _and_ adding to it? Since if you keep adding to the output and keep looping, it will continue endlessly. Maybe try `for(var i = 0, oLength = output.length; i < oLength; i++)`

Comment: yep, that's the thing :)

Comment: Not related to the infinite loop problem, but just a note that you're modifying the first parameter in place so if you call this with `unite(a, b, c)` then array `a` will be equal to the return value after the function has finished running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your code.

**1: You are adding items to an array as you iterate through it**

You set `output = arr1', then start walking`arr1`as part of`arguments`. Then you are adding items into`arr1/output` within the loop. These additional items are traversed and more items added.

**2: The unique test is flawed**

The first issue may not have been so bad if you ensured the items in the `output` array were unique. Unfortunately there is also an issue in your test for uniqueness in the output array. The current item is added for each entry in the output array that it doesn't match. If your output were `[1,2,3,4]` and the item you were comparing was `2`, it would get pushed onto the output 3 times because it does not match 1, 3 or 4.